# Search in loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array that contain groups of inputs. In this array the groups start at : `ACT/CONDITION-?`.

What I am trying to do is to create a new array for every group with all values that match the group number like `-1` or `-2` to be display separately in a report. It could be a many groups.

```
[
  "DESCRIPTION" => "Testting"
  "SUBHEADER-GENERAL-FOREMAN" => "AAA"
  "SUBHEADER-SUPERINTENDENT" => "BBB"
  "SUBHEADER-FOREMAN" => "CCC"
  "CONTRACT-NUMBER" => "K225"
  "ACT/CONDITION-1" => "Condition"  // First group start here
  "SAFETY-CATEGORY-1" => "Bump Hazard"
  "SAFETY-DEFICIENCY-1" => "Bump hazard"
  "OTHER-SAFETY-DEFICIENCY-1" => ""
  "POTENTIAL-HURT-1" => "1"
  "ROOT-CAUSE-1" => "Unknown"
  "OBSERVATION-DESCRIPTION-1" => "DDD"
  "HAVE-CORRECTIVE-MEASURES-BEEN-TAKEN?-1" => "No"
  "ARE-THERE-ANY-FURTHER-ACTION-REQUIRED?-1" => "No"
  "CORRECTIVE-ACTIONS-TAKEN/RECOMMENDED:-1" => ""
  "ACT/CONDITION-2" => "Act"              // Second group start here
  "SAFETY-CATEGORY-2" => "Barricade Entry"
  "SAFETY-DEFICIENCY-2" => "Unauthorized entry"
  "OTHER-SAFETY-DEFICIENCY-2" => ""
  "POTENTIAL-HURT-2" => "1"
  "ROOT-CAUSE-2" => "Enforcement"
  "OBSERVATION-DESCRIPTION-2" => "FFFF"
  "HAVE-CORRECTIVE-MEASURES-BEEN-TAKEN?-2" => "No"
  "ARE-THERE-ANY-FURTHER-ACTION-REQUIRED?-2" => "No"
  "CORRECTIVE-ACTIONS-TAKEN/RECOMMENDED:-2" => ""
]
```

Comment: u need to try first , ask question with the code that you have tried.

Comment: Where's your code please provide us your code don't give it to others as a homework.

Comment: please show some expected output as well.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put any tried code because no  getting any close output , but I tried having a foreach them increment a variable and  having a condition like this :   if($key == 'ACT/CONDITION-'.$n).

Answer (score 0):

I just make my version nesting the value for fun, hope it helps:

```
$array = [
    "DESCRIPTION" => "Testting",
    "SUBHEADER-GENERAL-FOREMAN" => "AAA",
    "SUBHEADER-SUPERINTENDENT" => "BBB",
    "SUBHEADER-FOREMAN" => "CCC",
    "CONTRACT-NUMBER" => "K225",
    "ACT/CONDITION-1" => "Condition",  // First group start here
    "SAFETY-CATEGORY-1" => "Bump Hazard",
    "SAFETY-DEFICIENCY-1" => "Bump hazard",
    "OTHER-SAFETY-DEFICIENCY-1" => "",
    "POTENTIAL-HURT-1" => "1",
    "ROOT-CAUSE-1" => "Unknown",
    "OBSERVATION-DESCRIPTION-1" => "DDD",
    "HAVE-CORRECTIVE-MEASURES-BEEN-TAKEN?-1" => "No",
    "ARE-THERE-ANY-FURTHER-ACTION-REQUIRED?-1" => "No",
    "CORRECTIVE-ACTIONS-TAKEN/RECOMMENDED:-1" => "",
    "ACT/CONDITION-2" => "Act",              // Second group start here
    "SAFETY-CATEGORY-2" => "Barricade Entry",
    "SAFETY-DEFICIENCY-2" => "Unauthorized entry",
    "OTHER-SAFETY-DEFICIENCY-2" => "",
    "POTENTIAL-HURT-2" => "1",
    "ROOT-CAUSE-2" => "Enforcement",
    "OBSERVATION-DESCRIPTION-2" => "FFFF",
    "HAVE-CORRECTIVE-MEASURES-BEEN-TAKEN?-2" => "No",
    "ARE-THERE-ANY-FURTHER-ACTION-REQUIRED?-2" => "No",
    "CORRECTIVE-ACTIONS-TAKEN/RECOMMENDED:-2" => ""
];

$new_array = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $getRep = substr($key, -1);

    if(is_numeric($getRep)) {
        $new_array[$getRep][$key] = $value;
    }else{
        $new_array[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

This are the results:

```
Array
(
    [DESCRIPTION] => Testting
    [SUBHEADER-GENERAL-FOREMAN] => AAA
    [SUBHEADER-SUPERINTENDENT] => BBB
    [SUBHEADER-FOREMAN] => CCC
    [CONTRACT-NUMBER] => K225
    [1] => Array
    (
        [ACT/CONDITION-1] => Condition
        [SAFETY-CATEGORY-1] => Bump Hazard
        [SAFETY-DEFICIENCY-1] => Bump hazard
        [OTHER-SAFETY-DEFICIENCY-1] => 
        [POTENTIAL-HURT-1] => 1
        [ROOT-CAUSE-1] => Unknown
        [OBSERVATION-DESCRIPTION-1] => DDD
        [HAVE-CORRECTIVE-MEASURES-BEEN-TAKEN?-1] => No
        [ARE-THERE-ANY-FURTHER-ACTION-REQUIRED?-1] => No
        [CORRECTIVE-ACTIONS-TAKEN/RECOMMENDED:-1] => 
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [ACT/CONDITION-2] => Act
        [SAFETY-CATEGORY-2] => Barricade Entry
        [SAFETY-DEFICIENCY-2] => Unauthorized entry
        [OTHER-SAFETY-DEFICIENCY-2] => 
        [POTENTIAL-HURT-2] => 1
        [ROOT-CAUSE-2] => Enforcement
        [OBSERVATION-DESCRIPTION-2] => FFFF
        [HAVE-CORRECTIVE-MEASURES-BEEN-TAKEN?-2] => No
        [ARE-THERE-ANY-FURTHER-ACTION-REQUIRED?-2] => No
        [CORRECTIVE-ACTIONS-TAKEN/RECOMMENDED:-2] => 
    )

)
```

Comment: Thanks EQrxJx thats helps me a lot!

Comment: @Vargas Please upvote and accept (if applicable), see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers